# Excel - how to convert a VALUETOTEXT() result back to DATETIME?

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a `datetime` column in Excel showing me nicely the datetime decimal value as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.

But when I convert it using `VALUETOTEXT()` I get the decimal version which is something like `44440.4618055556`.

How can I convert the text value back to datetime?

I tried `DATEVALUE()` function on the decimal above, and I get `#VALUE!` error

Comment: Either you have to format the cells as date or use TEXT() function like `=TEXT(VALUETOTEXT(A1),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")`

Comment: date format did nothing. Left the text as text. And TEXT() "worked" but it's now a string. I cannot use MONTH(A1) for example

Comment: Then you can directly use `=Month(VALUETOTEXT(A1))` to get month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are formatted numbers.

Use the double unary `--` to coerce the text back to a number, and apply date formatting `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` to the cell.
[image]

For what it's worth, note that applying General or Number format to a formatted date reveals the underlying number.

[image]